# Azure AD: Problems by configuration External User Self Service Registration service

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm trying to get the Self Service Resgistration for External Identies feature working.

In the Azure AD Portal I activate the feature and configure the process.

Now I want to try this. But where can I do that. I have not found a domain or link etc.
Do I need to create a Self-Dev. Web-interface for this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/self-service-sign-up-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have proceeded according to the documentation. Now I am done with it, but I don't know where to find the registration form.